# How to get user location on iOS5 while app in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location

I want to update user location support  from ios5 onwards.I think after ios6 onwards we can easily get user location both foreground and background mode.I want to also get user location on background mode in iOS5.Please help me.How to solve this issue?

Comment: I believe iOS 4 added location background mode; there shouldn't be anything you specifically need to do on ios5

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want/need to support iOS 5? Its a really old version, are you certain that a signifcant number of your users needs this support?

Comment: yes i need..its need for limited area.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting some screenshots for you to change the ios deployment target to 5.0 in latest xcode 8.2.1 and to fetch background location for ios 5.

Follow the Image step.

[image]

[image]

That all. Now Location should be fetch in iOS5's devices.

Thanks